# Can or should a blueprint xml file be inside a Karaf KAR file?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, blueprint-osgi

In a Karaf .kar file, should the blueprint xml file be inside the jar contained in the kar file OR should it be within the kar file itself.

Also, can a blueprint xml be inside a Karaf .kar file or must it be within the contained jar contained within the .kar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karaf allows to deploy plain blueprint.xml files but this is not covered by any standard. The blueprint spec conformant way to deploy a blueprint.xml is to put it into a bundle in the path OSGI-INF/blueprint.

You put the blueprint file into the jar and the jar into the kar.

Comment: When you say " put it into a bundle" do you mean put it into a JAR which is inside the KAR file? I mean, Karaf allows deploying of JAR or KAR files, KAR files contain JAR's, so I'm trying to work out where I am allowed to place blueprint xml files.

Comment: You put the blueprint file into the jar and the jar into the kar.